# Can Mathjax be used with https?

Tags: https, mathjax

Can Mathjax be used with https?

This script renders latex if the page is called http:..., but not https:...

```
    <script type='text/javascript' src='http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML&#038;ver=3.5.1'>
    </script>
```

Comment: Maybe you could consider downloading the JavaScript library and keeping it locally if you're concerned.   I'd recommend KaTeX over any JavaScript LaTeX math library - better performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, see http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/start.html#mathjax-cdn.  Use the script

```
<script type="text/javascript"
  src="https://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML">
</script>
```

Comment: Note from the future: cdn.mathjax.org is nearing its end-of-life, check https://mathjax.org/cdn-shutting-down for migration tips.